# Compare strings and only get certain strings that don't match

Tags: php, arrays, string, performance, variables

I have a few strings and i want the variables that don't equal each other.

For example:

```
$username
$email
$firstname
$lastname
$gender

$_POST['username'];
$_POST['email'];
$_POST['firstname'];
$_POST['lastname'];
$_POST['gender'];
```

i want to compare `$username` with `$_POST['username']`, `$email` with `$_POST['email']`, etc...

this is how i want to compare it:

`$username !== $_POST['username']`, etc...

how can i get the variables (not `$_POST` variables) that DON'T equal each other?

Comment: if($username!=$_POST['username']) use this....

Comment: Please check the syntax. @SoniyaReddy

Comment: @SougataBose am just comparing the username must be not equal to $_POST['username'] please let me know what i did wrong??

Comment: What issue are you getting @jasonmoqio?

Comment: @SoniyaReddy, should be `==` or `===` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with so many values, and if you know the fields that are coming at you, I would use arrays.

```
$vars = ['username' => 'value', 'email' => 'value',
        'firstname' => 'value', 'lastname' =>'value', 'gender'  => 'value'];
foreach($vars as $key => $value){
  if($_POST[$key] !== $value){
    //does not match
  }else{
    // does match
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the POST parameters are coming in as an array, the simplest approach would be to put your variables also in an array and calculate the difference using [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$variables = [
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'gender' => $gender
];

$non_matching = array_diff($variables, $_POST);

echo "Non matching variables: " . join(', ', array_keys($non_matching));
```

Which will print out something like:

```
Non matching variables: username, firstname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` to each array key and `$$key` to do.

```
$username = 'username';
$email    = 'email~';
$gender   = 'not gender';

$_POST['username']  = 'username';
$_POST['email']     = 'email';
$_POST['firstname'] = 'firstname';
$_POST['lastname']  = 'lastname';
$_POST['gender']    = 'gender';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ( !isset($$key) ) {
        echo 'The variable $' . $key . ' is undefined.' . PHP_EOL;
        continue;
    }
    echo 'Compare $_POST[\'' . $key . '\'] and $' . $key . ': ' . ( $value === $$key ? 'true' : 'false' ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
Compare $_POST['username'] and $username: true
Compare $_POST['email'] and $email: false
The variable $firstname is undefined.
The variable $lastname is undefined.
Compare $_POST['gender'] and $gender: false
```